# CAN standard frame and extended frame related

Tags: embedded

Is it possible to have both CAN standard frame and CAN extended frame coexist on a single CAN bus ?

can bus protocol allows this to happen?

Comment: To whomever to close votes to put this on Super User: that's a PC computer site! This question belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. Should be migrated to http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not done this yet, but to my knowledge it is possible to mix standard and extended frames as long as all CAN bus participants evaluate the IDE bit. Which means that all(!) CAN bus participants must be compliant to CAN 2.0B.

Comment: I doubt anyone uses the old version of CAN nowadays, but I believe that even in the original Bosch spec there was an IDE bit. Really old CAN nodes would therefore check the IDE bit too and realize "ah this is not for me, I should remain silent".

Answer (score 2):

The spec allows it and it is also common in modern bus systems.  If I remember the spec correctly, every CAN-Transceiver must at least tolerate the extended frame format without disturbing the bus.

So it should work as long as you don't have some ancient hardware on your bus.

Comment: Yes, I do this and it works OK:)